# Orthogonal projection in Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two closed subspaces of a given Hilbert space H. Let $h\in H$, $P(h|M)$ denotes the orthogonal projection of $h$ on the closed subspace $M$. 
Show that if $h\perp B$, then $P(h|A\vee B)=P(h|A)$, where $A\vee B$ is the closed the subspace spanned  by A and B.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** show that $\ h-P(h|A) \, \perp \, A\lor B$.